# is there an app which has running speed goal, measures speed, gives audio feedback?

Tags: running, tracking, 5k, app

checked the help centre and it said questions about gadgets are on topic, so I thought this was close enough.

Is there an android app which has a running speed goal, measures speed, gives audio feedback? I'm looking for one which uses the capabilities of the phone, and doesn't need extra dongles...

There are lots of apps which coach you to a 5k, which is very useful, but I find I need a new goal after I can run 5k, and I want to work on going faster much more than I want to run 10k... It takes over 45 minutes for me to "run" 5k, so there is a lot of room for improvement.

Edit: I know purchase recommendations are a no-no, but let me add I don't mind paying for a good app, but I'm not going to fork out every month for a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the of the premium / pro offerings provide this eg. 
[MapMyFitness MVP](http://about.mapmyfitness.com/2013/02/your-mvp-questions-answered/), [Runtastic](http://blog.runtastic.com/en/technology/runtastic-features/), [Endomondo Premium](http://techfuture.co.uk/2014/01/review-endomondo-sports-tracker/)

Answer (score 0):

[Forrest](https://apple.co/2HbNFsd) lets you create virtual opponents to race against that will run at whatever speed you choose. You get audio prompts throughout the workout to let you know of you progress.